# Changes in clarity-ui.min.css not working

Tags: vmware-clarity

I tried to add one more attribute to clarity modal css in clarity-ui.min.css but the changes are not reflecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any details about what you've done, its hard to understand what is going on. However, you should not directly edit `clr-ui.min.css` and instead write your own CSS that is included afterwards and overrides any values you need.